# Why is my google places nearbysearch returning atmosphere and contact data even though fields are defined?

Tags: javascript, google-places-api

I've made a very simple game for the young people in my Scout group to use during lockdown ([www.riddlesdenscouts.org.uk/monsters](http://www.riddlesdenscouts.org.uk/monsters)).

I am getting billed for contact and atmosphere data from my nearby search even though I have only requested the geometry.location field any suggestions? Thank you!

```
  const request = {
    location: {lat: lat, lng: lon},
    radius: 1500,
    fields: ["geometry.location"],
    type:"point_of_interest",
  };
  service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map); 
  service.nearbySearch(request, (results, status) => {
```

Comment: I suggest that you create a support case in your [Cloud Developer Console](https://developers.google.com/maps/support/#creating-a-support-case) so that the Maps people can take a look.

Comment: @RickyCuarez there is a big red warning on the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) page that says: *Nearby Search and Text Search return all of the available data fields for the selected place (a subset of the supported fields), and you will be billed accordingly. **There is no way to constrain Nearby Search or Text Search to only return specific fields**. To keep from requesting (and paying for) data that you don't need, use a Find Place request instead.*

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to constrain Nearby Search (or Text Search) to only return specific fields. To keep from requesting (and paying for) data that you don't need, use a **findPlaceFromQuery** instead.
But you will have to specify an input query string...
If you specify a wildcard character, you'll get list of nearby POI.

```js
const request = {
    locationBias: {
        center: {
            lat: lat,
            lng: lon
        },
        radius: 1500
    },
    query: "*",
    fields: ["geometry.location"],
};

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.findPlaceFromQuery(request, (results, status) => {
    if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            //console.log(results[i]);
        }
    }
});
```